# Yaml'ifying an XML file?

Tags: xml, ruby

I want to take an XML file (example is http://xboxapi.duncanmackenzie.net/gamertag.ashx?Gamertag=xpaulbettsx) and just turn it into a Ruby dictionary / ExpandoObject type thing, so I can do something like

```
gamertag_info = HowDoIDoThisPart.load("Example.xml")
puts gamertag_info.zone
>>> "Underground"
puts gamertag_info.recentgames
>>> <Array output>
```

I know that there's an easy way to do this - any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you're working with Rails, but [ActiveSupport](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Hash/ClassMethods.html#M001197) already includes this functionality.  Plus then you have access to all the YAML tools as well.

Answer (score 2):

I use the [Cobra vs Mongoose](http://cobravsmongoose.rubyforge.org/) library. From the docs:

```
require 'cobravsmongoose'
xml = '<alice><bob>charlie</bob><bob>david</bob></alice>'
CobraVsMongoose.xml_to_hash(xml)
# => { "alice" => { "bob" => [{ "$" => "charlie" }, { "$" => "david" }] } }
```